# Using Racing Wheel force feedback with a JavaScript game

Tags: javascript, force-feedback

I have a Thrustmaster T80 Racing Wheel that I am using while developing an online game with ThreeJS.

I have already made it so I can drive the car with the wheel and the game knows when I crash the car. But looking online I couldn't find a way to make the wheel 'rumble' or shake when the car crashes.

The wheel does support this on other (downloaded exe) games but it would be amazing if it was possible to achieve in a JS game, but I couldn't find any mention of doing this online.

Comment: Haptic feedback tends to be implemented on a per-device basis by most libraries because of driver differences (I remember back along that `SDL2`, a C++ library with haptic feedback support, was missing support for wireless XBox controllers, but other devices worked). It's a possibility that there might not be any browsers that support the particular wheel you're using. Which browsers have you tried? Have you been able to get the wheel to give haptic feedback through other programitc means (i.e. other libraries)?

Answer (score 1):

The term you are looking for is "haptic feedback". There seem to be a bunch of Javascript libraries that do this, for an example take a look at [Haptics.js](http://www.hapticsjs.org).

Comment: I tried this on mobile and it worked fine, but it doesn't work on my wheel, ill take a look at other similar libraries